# Share Eclipse Oomph preferences across different machines?

Tags: eclipse, cloud, share, oomph

I use Eclipse on three different computers and want to unify my preferences, such as UTF-8 encoding and code templates. This question has been asked before but that was before the integration of Oomph into Eclipse. Does Oomph have a feature like an "Ooomph Cloud" where I can login with my Google Account and sync my preferences?

Comment: The Oomph team and the Eclipse fundation are working on this. Check this: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg12867.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oomph only does the setup automation, but no synchronization or sharing on its own. You may want to try [Yatta Profiles](https://marketplace.yatta.de/profiles/) instead, which builds on top of Oomph. It allows sharing your IDE setup and workspace settings.

Comment: I couldn't get Yatta to transfer Eclipse preferences after hours of trying. Best solution is still file copying.

Comment: Yatta Profiles is no more, as of 2022 https://www.yatta.de/thoughts/sunsetting-profiles-hub

Answer (score 11):

Since the Eclipse Neon release Oomph supports sharing preferences across multiple machines. If you were not already prompted to opt into this new service you can enable it in Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Preference Synchronizer.

Comment: ...where you can set up an Eclipse.org account for saving your pref settings online.

Comment: You can register an Eclipse account at https://accounts.eclipse.org/user/register?destination=user

Comment: This does not function, unfortunately. I could not get Oomph to transfer preferences to the Eclipse User Storage Service (USS) after hours of trying. It would be a great solution if it worked, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sharing mechanism, but the setup file corresponding to your user scope: `user.setup` is stored on your machine:

```
USER_HOME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/setups/user.setup
```

You can share this XML file between different computers.

Comment: Preferences often contain machine-specific paths and locations. I'd recommend against sharing this kind of data. The preference synchronization mechanism let's you choose what preferences to sync, so that's probably safer.

Comment: @eike, I could get this to work after hours of trying.

Comment: What have you tried so far and how exactly did it fail?